# How do I get Seamless mode working under Oracle VM VirtualBox?

Tags: 10.10, virtualbox, virtualization

I'm use Oracle VM VirtualBox 3.2.8 (PUEL) on my Windows 7 as host.

I use seamless mode almost exclusively, and post upgrade to Ubuntu 10.10 the seamless mode is broken. Is there a way I can fix this or do I need to wait for the next release of VirtualBox?

(PS: I have looked at [Lifehacker's article](http://lifehacker.com/5633811/fix-virtualboxs-guest-additions-in-ubuntu-1010) and [other](http://www.unixmen.com/linux-tutorials/1157-install-guest-addition-in-ubuntu-1010-maverick-meerkat-fix) related [blog posts](http://www.sysprobs.com/maverick-meerkat-ubuntu-1010-virtualbox-328-ubuntu-1010-guest-additions-fix), and none of them work for me)

Comment: Have you installed the VirtualBox extensions?

Comment: @popey yes, I have

Comment: This maybe be a bug in VB, can you try reporting it to the VB devs and see if they can  offer more insight?

Comment: @Roland I had to update to VirtualBox 3.2.10, I'll post an answer. Thanks for the follow up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to update to [VirtualBox 3.2.10](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) to get the seamless mode back. Alternatively, if you don't want to update, you can just [download the updated Guest Additions CD](http://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions-r65553.iso) and install the new guest additions and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Install the package [virtualbox-ose-guest-x11](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/virtualbox-ose-guest-x11) on the Maverick guest.

Comment: I've installed it with no success.

Comment: Ah, that was what was recommended to me, and it worked. Odd. ;/

Answer (score 0):

Try [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/). I'm not using Windows as host, but I have experienced other problems with Oracle VirtualBox in Lucid. After switching to VMWare Player everything works fine and the seamless mode, called Unity, works like a charm.

To convert your VirtualBox image to VMWare see [this discussion](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=772419) (didn't try it).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm happy with VirtualBox.